# change the language of application when press menu in android

Tags: android

I want to change the language of my android when pressing the menu button, but it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
@Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

          //  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

            switch(item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.english:
                    Locale locale1 = new Locale("en");//fr is the code for french language
                    Locale.setDefault(locale1);
                    Configuration config1 = new Configuration();
                    config1.locale = locale1;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config1,
                          getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    clicked=false;
                    onCreate(new Bundle());
                    break;
                case R.id.french:
                    Locale locale2 = new Locale("fr");//fr is the code for french language
                    Locale.setDefault(locale2);
                    Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
                    config2.locale = locale2;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2,
                          getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    clicked=false;
                    onCreate(new Bundle());

                    break;

            }
            return true;

        }
```

I added menu items to menu.xml file, but I don't know why it is not working

Comment: Could you show `onCreate(...)` method?

Comment: @neworld it is the original onCreate method.

      
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    }

Comment: Use @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, just use

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

instead of :

```
onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```